# Why is ProgressEvent.lengthComputable false?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am loading a JSON file using XMLHttpRequest in Google Chrome, Safari and Firefox. In all three browsers I am receiving `ProgressEvent`s which correctly show the `.loaded` property. However the `.lengthComputable` property is false and the `.total` property is zero. I have checked that the `Content-Length` HTTP header is being sent and is correct - it is. The response is being gzip-encoded, but the `Content-length` correctly shows the encoded length (before decompression).

Why would the total length not be available in my `ProgressEvent`s?

Here are the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: "hKXdZA"
Date: Wed, 20 Jun 2012 20:17:17 GMT
Expires: Wed, 20 Jun 2012 20:17:17 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=3600
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars: $0.000108
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage: ms=2 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 621606
```

Note: the file is being served via Google App Engine.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var req;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(req.overrideMimeType){
        req.overrideMimeType( "text/json" );
    }
}else{
    req = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

// Listen for progress events
req.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {
    console.log(event, event.lengthComputable, event.total);
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        self.progress = event.loaded / event.total;
    } else if (this.explicitTotal) {
        self.progress = Math.min(1, event.loaded / self.explicitTotal);
    } else {
        self.progress = 0;
    }
    self.dispatchEvent(Breel.Asset.ON_PROGRESS);
}, false);

req.open('GET', this.url);
```

Note: The `console.log` in that code is showing hundreds of events with up to date `.loaded`s but `.lengthComputable` is always false and `.total` is always zero. `self` refers to the object responsible for this `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Can we see the javascript code you have that's looking at this data?

Comment: have you tried using this on a non-google app engine server?  If `lengthComputable` is false than the xhr object doesn't know how long the file is.  We use GAE here and have massive problems with most of it's functionality -- this wouldn't be surprising.

Comment: I have tried another server but it is giving me chunked encoding therefore no Content-Length. In this instance lengthComputable == false would make sense. I will have to try another one later. Seems to me by the headers that GAE is behaving - but I'm just as suspicious as you are about it.

Comment: See its compability : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent.lengthComputable

Answer (score 19):

If lengthComputable is false within the XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent, that means the server never sent a Content-Length header in the response.

If you're using nginx as a proxy server, this might be the culprit, especially if it's not passing the Content-Length header from the upstream server through the proxy server to the browser.

Comment: If you are setting a content-length header that is being ignored, you must also set the buffer size of your response to be able to hold the bytes your are sending.  Otherwise in HTTP 1.1 it will revert to chunking the response.

Comment: Or, many years later, when using gzip'd content in Chrome, even when the right headers have been set. :-(

Answer (score 12):

Meanwhile 2017, things are fine in Firefox, but Chrome does not show the progress for gzip'd content.

This seems to be caused by the specifications once being unclear if `loaded` and `total` refer to the compressed or uncompressed content. [Since](https://github.com/whatwg/xhr/commit/b9f6bcf9800963eb450b20cc96492a670fb96a99) Jun 26, 2014 [the XMLHttpRequest specifications](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) make clear they should refer to the transmitted (compressed) content:

> 6.1. Firing events using the `ProgressEvent` interface
>
> [...] given *transmitted* and *length* [...]  fire an event [...] `ProgressEvent`, with the `loaded` attribute initialized to *transmitted*, and if *length* is not 0, with the `lengthComputable` attribute initialized to true and the `total` attribute initialized to *length*.

However, the 2015 Chromium bug report ["XHR's progress events should handle gzipped content"](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=463622) explains that things were different, and states:

> when encoded, `total` stays to be 0 and `lengthComputable` is not set

The event itself is still fired, and `event.loaded` is still populated. But Chrome is decompressing gzip'd content on the fly and (today) sets `loaded` to the resulting decompressed length, not to the *transmitted* length. This cannot be compared to the value of the `Content-Length` header, as that's the length of the *compressed* content, so `loaded` will become larger than the content length.

At best one could assume some compression factor to compare `loaded` against `Content-Length`, or make the server add some custom header to provide the original length or the true compression factor, assuming Chrome's on-the-fly decompression will not change.

I've no idea what Chrome does for other values for `Content-Encoding`.

Comment: At least: I assume the value of `event.loaded` being the decompressed size (rather than the transmitted length) is not related to https://crbug.com/763700...

Answer (score 9):

use **req.upload.addEventListener** for upload

*req.addEventListener* event.lengthComputable will always be false

```
req.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {
    console.log(event, event.lengthComputable, event.total);
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        self.progress = event.loaded / event.total;
    } else if (this.explicitTotal) {
        self.progress = Math.min(1, event.loaded / self.explicitTotal);
    } else {
        self.progress = 0;
    }
    self.dispatchEvent(Breel.Asset.ON_PROGRESS);
}, false);
```

Comment: I have seen the `req.addEventListener` `event.lengthComputable` be true, as well. It seems to be false for large requests: the one I tried was a 10MB JPG. I have not done extensive testing, but you may be right that `req.upload`'s `lengthComputable` is true more often.

Comment: ...but like the name suggests: that's for uploads from browser to server, not for downloads from server to browser.

Answer (score 4):

Just set in PHP or apache/nginx

```
header("Content-Encoding: none");
```

problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Content-Length in the controller code. This will set the `event.lengthComputable`.

```
var fileSize = new FileInfo(filePathAbs).Length;
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileSize.ToString());
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName);

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open('GET', '/EReader/GetDocument?p=@Model.EncodedTempFilePath');
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
req.onprogress = function (event) { 
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        percentage = Math.floor(event.loaded * 100 / event.total); // give the percentage
        var elem = document.getElementById("bar");
        elem.style.width = percentage + '%';
    }
};
```

Comment: hello, you just need to check if it is an chrome based browser, by checking for uaData ("userAgent data") available or not. content length information is set by event.loaded and event total. then you get information either way. by settin (event.lengthComputable
||!chrome). works for me.