# JS ProgressEvent is only fired when finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, progress, xmlhttprequest-level2

I am having some problems getting my upload progress bar to work properly.

According to the XMLHttpRequest Level 2 specs, I attached event listeners for loadstart and progress like this:

```
var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
xhr.upload.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {progressCallback(0);});
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
    progressCallback(e.loaded / e.total);
});    

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    xhr: function () {
        return xhr;
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    // Finish stuff
})
```

The file is correctly uploaded but the progress listener is only called once the request is finsished with 100% (e.total == e.loaded)

Is anything wrong with the code above or is it necessary to configure the server in any special way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the total size of the file can't be determine, `e.loaded` and `e.total` are zero. You can check this inside your `progress` function:

```
if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    progressCallback(e.loaded / e.total);
}
```

The server must also send `Content-Length` which is defined in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/#interface-progressevent):

> If the length of the HTTP entity body is known through the Content-Length header, initialize the lengthComputable attribute to true and initialize the total attribute to the length.

Please also notice that the progress bar don't work with the `file:` protocol.

I can really recommend the Mozilla docs which are very extensive - [Using XMLHTTPRequest Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Does the server have to deliver something so that lengthComputable becomes true?
Because I already send the Content-Length correctly...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127654/why-is-progressevent-lengthcomputable-false . The server has to send the `Content-Length` too.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Which server and programming language do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue myself, where my event handler function for `progress` events on `XMLHttpRequest` was executed only once -- when the upload was complete.

The cause of the problem ended up being simple -- in Google Chrome (possibly other browsers too, I did not test), the `progress` event will only fire in succession if the upload had been running for a second or two. In other words, if your upload finishes quickly, then you'll likely just get one 100% `progress` event.

Here's an example of code whose `progress` event only fires once at 100% complete ( https://jsfiddle.net/qahs40r6/ ):

```
$.ajax({
  xhr: function()
  {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        console.log("Upload ", Math.round(percentComplete*100) + "% complete.");
      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/echo/json/",
  data: {json: JSON.stringify(new Array(20000))}
});
```

Console output:

```
Upload  100% complete.
```

But if you add an extra zero to the size of the array (increasing the payload size by a factor of 10 -- https://jsfiddle.net/qahs40r6/1/):

```
$.ajax({
  xhr: function()
  {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        console.log("Upload ", Math.round(percentComplete*100) + "% complete.");
      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/echo/json/",
  data: {json: JSON.stringify(new Array(200000))}
});
```

Then you get the normal progression of `progress` events:

```
Upload  8% complete.
Upload  9% complete.
Upload  19% complete.
Upload  39% complete.
Upload  50% complete.
Upload  81% complete.
Upload  85% complete.
Upload  89% complete.
Upload  100% complete.
```

This behavior depends upon how fast your Internet connection is, so your mileage will vary. For example, if you take the first example and use Chrome Developer Tools to slow your connection to a simulated "Slow 3G", then you will see the series of `progress` events.

Similarly, if you are developing locally and uploading data to a local web server, you'll likely never see `progress` events because the upload will finish instantly.