# Why does Gzip not work on Chrome?

Tags: python, google-chrome, gzip

I am trying to see the effects of gzip on my website. Currently, I am using flask and I put a print statements to observe the effects of gzip:

```
def compress(self, app, response):
    gzip_buffer = BytesIO()
    print "Before compress", len(response.get_data())
    with GzipFile(mode='wb',
                  compresslevel=app.config['COMPRESS_LEVEL'],
                  fileobj=gzip_buffer) as gzip_file:
        gzip_file.write(response.get_data())
    print "After compress", len(gzip_buffer.getvalue())
    return gzip_buffer.getvalue()
```

My terminal prints,

```
Before compress 2653151
After compress 58912
```

However, when I open up chrome developer tools, I am not seeing the effects of gzip being registered:

[image]

And this is the request:

[image]
Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Known issue: https://crbug.com/763700

Comment: Maybe related to the bug, maybe not: when subscribing to `ProgressEvent` the value of `event.loaded` [is showing the decompressed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127654/why-is-progressevent-lengthcomputable-false/47287125#47287125) as well.

Comment: @Josh, that comment sounds like an answer to me?