# Length computable is returning false when we use nginx server

Tags: javascript, nginx, ionic-framework, addeventlistener

I think the javascript method lengthComputable is returns false always when we use nginx server. Is there any solution to overcome this problem? Or I need any other method to altering the following method. Thanks

```
function updateProgress(oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
    if (!size) {
      size = oEvent.total;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you've misconfigured nginx - I have no such issue. Is the resource a static resource (file) or something dynamic (reading a database or some such) - is the response size known on the server side?

Comment: Basically I am a beginner. So I learn most of the stuffs from StackOverflow. I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127654/why-is-progressevent-lengthcomputable-false) answer also from stack overflow and I came to this conclusion. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11848934/7274336)

Comment: so, you've read those answers, do they apply?