# ProgressEvent.total is 0 for 3D model deployed on Netlify, but works in local environment

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, netlify

I am using Three.js and GLTFLoader to load a 3D model onto my site. Locally, the resource is loaded without any problems, though when deployed to Netlify the ProgressEvent has LengthComputable as false and the total as 0, even though in the network tab I can see the resource being loaded as seen in the pictures below:

[ProgressEvent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI0oD.jpg)

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1lOy.jpg)

Originally I tried to follow an option from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127654/why-is-progressevent-lengthcomputable-false), where you set the content-length header, but as you can see in the picture the content-length header is already set in the response.

Any ideas how to get this resource to load and work on the site?

(I can post the three.js code if you would like, but I don't think it is this since it works locally, or the 3D object - which works also on https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ with no problems. Are there any settings in Netlify that I could change?)